# Kendo grid jQuery animate() issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I'm having an issue with a kendo grid that has a child grid inside the detailInit();

demo: [kendo dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@crunchfactory/iJuXa)

When a user opens the details area for a row, I scroll the row to the top and open it:

```
// animate the scroll
this.element.find(".k-grid-content").animate({
scrollTop: distance
}, 400);
```

my problem is the grid inside the detailInit is also scrolling, so I thought, np, just define the selector a little tighter..

I tried:

```
.find("#grid > .k-grid-content")
```

and others, but it won't allow it to scroll, etc...

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there. When you use `#grid > .k-grid-content` the selector doesn't returns any element because `this.element` already is `#grid`, so there is no `#grid` under `#grid`. But there is `.k-grid-content` under it indeed, so...

```
this.element.find("> .k-grid-content")
```

should work for you. [Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/OJUCu).